# How to force log out of Service Provider orgs when logging out of Identity Provider org?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

Scenario: Hub and spoke org strategy with one Salesforce org acting as a SAML IdP for the other N orgs.

Is there a way to force a log out on the SPs when a user manually logs out of the IdP org?  I was trying to think of ways to use logout URLs to accomplish it but the fact that there could be any number of SPs is throwing that out.  Any ideas?